# UIScrollView: View inside don't fit properly, weird behaviour, view snaps back on touch

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I am having trouble with a UIScrollView... I have researched a lot and found cases that were similar yet the solutions never seemed to work so here's a little explanation (it's quite hard to explain)

I have a viewcontroller that contains a UIScrollView and I load a couple of view controllers inside that uiscrollview... I instatnite them and then I add them to the scrollView like this...

```
viewController1.view.frame = scrollView1.bounds
var frame0 = viewController1.view.frame
frame0.origin.x = 0
viewController1.view.frame = frame0

self.addChildViewController(viewController1)
self.scrollView1.addSubview(viewController1.view)
viewController1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

viewController2.view.frame = scrollView1.bounds
var frame01 = viewController2.view.frame
frame01.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
viewController2.view.frame = frame01

self.addChildViewController(viewController2)
self.scrollView1.addSubview(viewController2.view)
viewController2.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

...
```

after that I configure the scroll view as follows

```
self.scrollView1.contentSize  = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 5, self.view.frame.height)
scrollView1.delaysContentTouches = false
```

Times 5 because there are 5 ViewControllers

(The scroll view has paging enabled)

Now this method works quite well and all views are loaded inside the scroll view and I can swipe trough my views however here's the problem.
My first view is loaded fine, then when I swipe to the right I see that the second view is offset to the top and a part of it is hidden, then when I touch a button inside the view it suddenly snaps to the bottom in it's place... This is really annoying because it makes the user interface really irritating since a part of it is hidden...

I have made an illustration of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppEQ5.jpg

I have tried a bunch of things like setting

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

or

```
self.scrollView1.clipsToBounds = true
```

but still the same problem occurs. I also thaught it was my navigation bar since the view containing the scrollview is located inside a ViewController that has a navigation bar (from uinavigationcontroller)

So for testing purposes I tried it without a navigation controller and bar but still the same kind of problem occurred. It's really frustrating and I can't seem to find a solution.

However I do have to say when the scrollview was located inside the ViewController with navigationBar and I set

```
self.scrollView1.contentSize  = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 5, self.view.frame.height - 66)
```

(Notice the -66)
Then the snapping problem didn't occur, however this wasn't the effect I was looking for since the scrollview needed to fill up the whole view, also the view inside the UIScrollView wasn't completely visible then so that wasn't a solution either.

I also taught it was maybe because my constraints were differently set up on one of the view controllers I loaded so I tried it with initiating the same type of view controller a few times still the same problem occurred...

(So I have tried a lot but no matter what I try to do it gets worse or another problem occurs for each view moves in either direction then I add     self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false but then the snapping returns etc. etc.)

Hopefully somebody has some suggestions to solve this
(If I you need some more illustrations etc. then I will provide these too.)

Thank You

Comment: Referring to the code above, what's the purpose of adding purchaseAmountViewController?

Comment: That's a mistake has to be ViewController1 too I changed my code to ViewController1 etc. to be more clear probably forgot to change that one thanks! I will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, there are 2 things to try:

1. Some of child view controllers may contain scroll views and their automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false needs to be set other than the parent view controller
2. A very helpful way to find out is to turn on view debugging. Run the project, then go to Xcode > View Debugging > Show View Frames. See if the child views of the child view controllers are misaligned along the top. If they are properly aligned (top all flushed), it means the problem lies in the individual child views.

Comment: Thank you, I will try the second point for sure. I don't have any scroll views inside of them that I know of...